# why do pullbacks of closed forms along homotopic functions only differ by an exact one?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

I am trying the get a deeper understanding of the following lemma:

> Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be open; and let futhermore $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be open with $U \times [0,1] \subset V$. We also define $i_t: U \rightarrow V$ by $x \mapsto (x,t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$. By $\Omega^k(V)$ we denote the space of differential k-forms on V. Then for each closed $\varphi \in \Omega^k(V)$ there exists a $\psi \in \Omega^k(U)$ such that $$i_1^* \varphi - i_0^* \varphi =d\psi $$

This lemma was originally introduced as a mere technical construction to package away the heavy lifting of the proof of the Poincarè-lemma, but we have used it multiple times since and i came around to taking it as a quite deep result, since it of course yields that pullbacks of closed forms along homotopic functions only differ by an exact form, thereby establishing a connection between forms and notions from topology.

I would therefore like to get a bigger picture of what is happening here, why the above lemma should be true *morally*. I feel that I'm not quite grokking what is going on.

I skimmed through wikipedia and a couple of textbooks and came across de Rham-Groups, which we did not cover in our lecture, but that seem to have something to do with this (because you look at forms modulo the exact ones). I also tried throwing Stokes Theorem at the last equation, but it did not yield anything illuminating.

As a post-script, answers like "the only way to get intuition on this is to wait for an actual differential geometry/algebraic topology class" would be fine, as well as links or just some key-words to look up.

Thanks!

Comment: The intuition for this is exactly that De Rham Cohomology measures the same thing as singular cohomology, so homotopic objects are cohomologous. In some sense, the Poincaré Lemma *is* the intuition for the lemma you provided.

Comment: For example, think of the one form induced by a purely rotation vector field about the origin. The non-exactness is exactly what gives rise to the nontrivial cohomology of the punctured plane (where the one form is smooth) (the Wikipedia page on De Rham Cohomology has more details). Homotopic forms may stretch and move around the underlying vectors a lot, but the overall torsion around the origin remains the same and detects the same nontrivial cohomology class.

Comment: I think the proof is quite enlightening, actually. $\psi = \mathscr I \phi$, where $\mathscr I$ integrates out $dt$ from $0$ to $1$. In some sense, you can visualize this with Stokes’s Theorem: Since $d\phi=0$, the integral of $\phi$ over the boundary of $\sigma\times [0,1]$ gives $0$ for any $n$-chain $\sigma\subset X$. But $\partial(\sigma\times [0,1]) = \sigma_1-\sigma_0+\partial\sigma\times [0,1]$.

Comment: Oh. You have the result slightly misstated. $\phi$ should be a form on $V$ and $\psi$ should be a form on $U$.

Comment: @TedShifrin oh you're right, that made no sense. I edited the question.